# 502 Bad gateway with spring rest template

Tags: spring, http, resttemplate

I am trying to access a url by using restTemplate. I can access the same url on browser or by running the app locally. But in remote environment, I receive:

> 502 Bad Gateway: [no body]

The way I am calling the url is :

```
  final Map myMap = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Map.class);
```

I have no idea why I am getting it while I am able to access same url by running application locally. I would appreciate for any kind of ideas.

Comment: might be due to ssl certificates `An HTTP 502 status code (Bad Gateway) indicates that CloudFront wasn't able to serve the requested object because it couldn't connect to the origin server. Topics. SSL/TLS negotiation failure between CloudFront and a custom origin server. Origin is not responding with supported ciphers/protocols.`